# Can't access keys in the dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror

```
books = ['book1', 'book2', 'book3']
names = ['anas', 'jana', 'mo']
biglist = [{'anas' : {'book1' : 0, 'book2' : -2, 'book3' : 3}}, 
            {'jana' : {'book1' : 5, 'book2' : 0, 'book3' : -3}}, 
            {'mo' : {'book1' : 1, 'book2' : 5, 'book3' : 3}}]
```

I was planning to calculate the average for each book(excluding the zeros), so i came up with this list comprehension:

```
ratings={book:[biglist[i][names[j]][book] for i, _ in enumerate(biglist)] for book in books for j in range(len(names))}
sum_of_ratings = {book:sum(ratings[book]) for book in books}
avg_of_ratings =  {book:sum_of_ratings[book]/len(ratings[book]) for book in books}
```

But when i run the code it gives this output:

```
ratings={book:[biglist[i][names[j]][book] for i, _ in enumerate(biglist)] for book in books for j in range(len(names))}
KeyError: 'anas'
```

Apparently, it doesn't find the keys even though is the same as the ones in the list.

> NOTE : i'm not going to be using any built in functions in order to
>    compute the average.

Comment: Your list comprehension attempts to find each "name" in every dict, but each name in your data it only in a single dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comprehension uses three different methods to iterate over a list; just use the simplest one!

You also forgot to exclude the zeroes from the average calculation (you'd need to take the `len` of the list minus the zero elements).  It's simpler to just use `statistics.mean` and filter the zeroes out first.

You also don't even need the "user" keys since they aren't a part of this calculation, so doing lookups based on those adds more unnecessary complexity.  Just take the `values` of those dicts:

```
>>> ratings = {book: [d[book] for u in biglist for d in u.values()] for book in books}
>>> ratings
{'book1': [0, 5, 1], 'book2': [-2, 0, 5], 'book3': [3, -3, 3]}
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> avg_ratings = {book: mean(r for r in ratings[book] if r != 0) for book in books}
>>> avg_ratings
{'book1': 3, 'book2': 1.5, 'book3': 1}
```

Or you could just condense the whole thing into a single comprehension:

```
avg_ratings = {book: mean(
    d[book] for u in biglist for d in u.values() if d[book] != 0
) for book in books}
```

Comment: Is it possible to compute the average without using the 'mean' built in function?

Comment: Sure, there's always a more difficult way to do things.  :)

Comment: This is for a project that's why i'm not allowed to use any built in functions.

Comment: Your original code uses `sum`, `enumerate`, `len`, and `range`, all builtin functions.  Regardless, if you're specifically not allowed to use `mean`, just implement your own version; that's the easy part!